# Open file from filezilla to gvim in a new tab

Tags: vim, filezilla

I'm trying to figure out how to tell filezilla to open any file in the current gvim session (instead of creating multiple instance).

I already know that I have the modify the custom editor line input.

```
"/usr/bin/gvim" --remote-tab-silent param?
```

Thanks

Edit: I use Ubuntu Linux

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a -p flag to the gvim call (-p to open each file en a new tab). Like

```
"/usr/bin/gvim -p"
```

Comment: When I try to add that, I get this error from filezilla: "The file selected as default editor does not exist". I've as well tried `"/usr/bin/gvim" -p` but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`FileZilla -> Edit -> Settings -> File Editing -> Use custom editor ->`**`/usr/bin/gvim --remote-tab-silent`**

Also

In the **`gvim.desktop`** desktop file (**`/usr/share/applications/`** for most GNU/Linux systems) look for the **"Exec"** line. It will probably be like this:

**`Exec=gvim -f %F`**

Change the Exec line to:

**`Exec=gvim -p --remote-tab-silent %F`**

You may also need to change the **`StartupNotify`** value to **`false`** if it is currently set **`true`**, or your Vim may not respond properly when the file is already open in a tab.